# How to force subscriber to have foreign key WITH CHECK?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, replication, transactional-replication

I know by default SQL Server replication adds `WITH NOCHECK` and `NOT FOR REPLICATION` to the foreign keys after transactional replication. But is there are way, where I can avoid these code changes made by replication. We use a compare tool and these small changes get highlighted. I have an understanding, why they are placed, but some requirements have come up in which I want to have `WITH CHECK`s constraint at subscriber side as well. I just want to know if somehow we can avoid these few additions and changes to articles scripts both on publisher and subscriber.

The orignal script looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tablename] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__E__06] FOREIGN KEY ([eId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table] ([Id]) 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tablename] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__E_S__05] FOREIGN KEY ([nId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table] ([Id])
GO
```

Altered script at subscriber appeared as this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tablename] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__E__06] FOREIGN KEY ([eId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table] ([Id]) NOT FOR REPLICATION
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tablename] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__E_S__05] FOREIGN KEY ([nId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table] ([Id]) NOT FOR REPLICATION
GO
```

I want to avoid these changes and in article properties pane, I have seleced True for contraints to be copied at subscriber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know by default SQL Server replication adds WITH NOCHECK and NOT FOR REPLICATION

Not quite.  By default they are CHECK or NOCKECK to match the constraint on the publisher, but set to NOT FOR REPLICATION, so updates from the distribution agent do not fire the constraint.

You can choose

1) Whether or not the constraints are copied in the first place in the article properties, by setting or 0x200 flag (2nd byte, 2nd bit) in the schema_option bitmask in [sp_addarticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> 0x200 Replicates foreign key constraints. If the referenced table is
>   not part of a publication, all foreign key constraints on a published
>   table are not replicated

2) Whether they are created with the NOT FOR REPLICATION option at the subscriber, by setting or clearing the 0x20000 flag (3rd byte, 2nd bit)

> 0x20000   Replicates FOREIGN KEY constraints as NOT FOR REPLICATION so
>   that the constraints are not enforced during synchronization.

By default this nibble is 3, as the 0x10000 flag that controls check constraints is also set.  So set this nibble to 0x10000 to create FK constraints without the NOT FOR REPLICATION option and to 0x00000 to create both FK constraints and check constraints without the NOT FOR REPLICATION option.

See generally [Control Behavior of Triggers and Constraints in Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/control-behavior-of-triggers-and-constraints-in-synchronization?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I used GUI for the creation of the publication, Is there a way that these properties can be changed/set at there? I could only set True/False options at that point

Comment: so, i figured out how to set it, but confusion remains... my current value for schema is `0x000003454DFF7FDF` and i think, check constraints bit is enable, but still getting `with nocheck` and `not for replication` at subscriber???

Comment: 0x20000 is not exposed in the SSMS GUI.  To zero the 0x20000 bit, change 0x000003454DF**F**7FDF to 0x000003454DF**D**7FDF

Comment: One thing more at publisher side `Not for Replication` also gets added to Primary keys, is that avoidable as well?

Comment: Its just that, I want to avoid any changes to the original scripts as much as possible, was looking for some SPs for publication as well that can block these changes, but couldn't found yet!

Comment: You could consider initializing from backup instead of a snapshot.  Then the subscriber starts a just a restored copy of the publisher. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/initialize-a-transactional-subscription-from-a-backup?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Ok, I just gone through the documentation, but not clear, after initialization it will be pointed to the live database? or will it have to reinitialized with backup every time I add an article to it.

Comment: See https://repltalk.com/2019/01/03/deep-dive-on-initialize-from-backup-for-transactional-replication/